# Symfony2 view is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')

Tags: symfony

I would like to show an register link in the view's in symfony2 only users of a valid ip range.

Exists anything like this:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') and ip {'xy'} %}
    <a href="#">Register</a>
{% endif %}
```

Or should i implement a logic in php for this case?

Comment: You should implement your own `voter`. Example of oposite case (exclude ip) can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html)

Comment: Such information should be passed to view from controller. Don't couple the view with existence of such high-level utilities.

Comment: What do you think if you use `{% if app.request.getClientIp == 'xxx.x.x.xx' %}...{% endif %}`?

Comment: I will only show some links, as example register or forgot password in the intranet and for the public i will disable / not show this kind of links. Many thanks @Javad, i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

After that you can use your condition in view

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')  %}
    <a href="#">Register</a>
{% endif %}
```

For more detail see
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html